# Codeigniter clear my session data sometimes automatic

Tags: codeigniter-2

I’ve a very strange problem. I’ve my user data stored in sessions when people are loggin in to the site. This is working as it should, but sometimes when i navigate around on my site, Codeigniter loggin me out automatic out of the wind.

Anyone got this problem before and know a solution?

Comment: If you are using ajax on your site, this is a very common and known concurrency problem. [Here is some discussion on Github about it.](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1900)

Answer (score 0):

Check session time.....

application/config/config.php

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

The number of seconds you would like the session to last. The default value is 2 hours (7200 seconds). If you would like a non-expiring session set the value to zero: 0

For more details...

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I agree with Delvin Paul, and also I suggest to store session in DB. It will works better.
For more, read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I have tried the above piece of code but still my session data automatically destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Hi please make the following changes in the system/libraries/sessions.php file.

```
public $sess_encrypt_cookie;
public $sess_use_database;
public $sess_table_name;
public $sess_expiration;
public $sess_expire_on_close;
public $sess_match_ip;
public $sess_match_useragent;
public $sess_cookie_name;
public $cookie_prefix;
public $cookie_path;
public $cookie_domain;
public $cookie_secure;
public $sess_time_to_update;
public $encryption_key;
public $flashdata_key;
public $time_reference;
public $gc_probability;
public $userdata;
public $CI;
public $now;
```

I had same problem custom session was going destroy automatically after some interval of time.